# Draggable Parent and Child Divs move at the same time not independently

Tags: reactjs

In React bootstrap I have three components A, B and C :
the Component "A" which create an instance of a generic and Draggable component "C" and fill it with a  material-react-table V2 and also has a button which opens another instance of component "C" with the component B.
The problem is that when I drag one the other also drag.

[Image Before Drag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J72h.png)

[Image After Drag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1UiA.png)

Comment: Can you please provide reproducible examples or code snippets, so it's clearer to understand the problem and provide solutions?